# PHP Configuration on IIS 6 Mysql extension is not loaded

Tags: mysql, iis-6, php5, php

I have limited knowledge of PHP. I would really appreciate your help. I have the problem with "PHPMyAdmin is not working because mysql extension is not loaded."

I checked phpinfo and all other extensions(GD,MS SQL,etc) are loaded except mysql.

```
Web Server: IIS 6
PHP Version: 5.2.6 and I also tried 5.2.17.
MySQL version: 4.1
```

I tried the following code in php.

```
<?php   
echo '<br> php running';
mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
?>
```

It only prints out php running and it doesn't connect to the database.

I checked my web.config file and the connection string is as follow and it is working on .net

```
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=users;Uid=root;Pwd=password;CharSet=utf8;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn found it. I had to copy libmysql.dll to system32 folder. Cheers.